# Can't show grub screen

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04

I've installed Ubuntu 10.04 server edition and want to enter the recovery mode.

After reboot the system, it directly enter the login window, no grub screen shows.

If I click esc when booting the system, it stops loading and shows a blinking cursor infinitely.

What's the problem here? Is there some way to trouble shooting?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be pressing Shift to go into recovery mode, not Escape.

Comment: I can vouch for this, but would you know why Ubuntu has started hiding the Grub screen?

Comment: I don't know why, but I find it actually a good idea. It is the sole OS on my PC and I don't want my start up to be slowed down by waiting for me to choose from a single "normal" boot option plus recovery, as I am only likely to choose recovery mode in less than 1% of boots.

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal and edit /etc/default/grub:

```
$ sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Change the lines:

```
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
```

to:

```
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=false
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
```

Note that the original values may be different.  When you're done editing, save the file and run:

```
$ sudo update-grub
```

Reboot and you should see the grub menu.

More information about grub in Ubuntu is available [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1195275).

Comment: Thanks elmugrat, but the problem is that I can't sudo, that's why I want to enter the recovery mode. I've mistakenly removed myself from sudoers

Comment: and my current /etc/default/grub says: GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0 GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true GRUB_TIMEOUT=10

Comment: Oh ok.  When the screen says "Grub loading..." or something like that and there's a countdown, hit escape and it should bring the menu up.